# In C# Hashtable is passed by reference or by value by default?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I would like to know if by default is Hashtable passed by reference or by value?

Comment: [Passing Parameters (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Parameters to functions are passed by value unless otherwise specified (ref and out)

Comment: You can also check out what Jon Skeets says about [parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, all parameters are passed by value. But `HashTable` is a reference type, so the value being passed is a reference to the actual `HashTable`, if that makes sense.

It thus means the HashTable is not being copied when you pass it as a parameter, but if you try to overwrite the parameter value like so:

```
private void SomeMethod(HashTable ht)
{
   ...
   ht = new HashTable();
   ...
}
```

then it will not work, because you're overwriting the value parameter, not the actual `HashTable`.

Answer (score -1):

The reference to that hashtable is passed by value (unless you specify `ref`).